# How do I add bookmarks to a watermarked secured PDF eBook?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, copy-protection, watermark

I have purchased a few PDF eBooks (RPG rulebooks) and they come with a set of bookmarks, but with such "technical" books, I would really like to be able to add new bookmarks for easy reference. (Normal PDF bookmarks would be best, because I'd like to use them on my tablet as well.)

However, these PDF files are secured ("watermarked" it said) and I cannot edit anything about them. The PDF security info that Adobe reader gives looks like this:

```
Security: Password Security
All contents of the document are encrypted ...
Document Restrictions Summary:
  Printing: Allowed
  ...
  Content Copying: Allowed
  ...
  Commenting: Not allowed
  ...
```

Anything I can do?

Note that while it says "Password Security" I myself don't have any password for this file, I just open it with a PDF reader and can then read it just fine.

<sub>Note: Personally, I don't care whether the document is still secured afterwards or whether doing anything is "legal" in anyone's opinion or some random jurisdiction. I payed good money for that document, I don't plan on sharing it, I just want some post-it notes in my tablet ready rulebooks ;-) .</sub>

Comment: Since printing is allowed, can you print it as another PDF (using virtual printer) then operate on the "printed" PDF? This is OS dependent. I know macOS has such a PDF printer built-in.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF with DRM can be one of several types but the simplest of all is a PDF without password that allows say assistive reading aloud.

These come in 2 sub sets

- 1 those where the Adobe optional restriction is only upheld by Acrobat Reader or Chrome / Edge / Foxit or subsidiary browsers etc. Those can be easily edited in a derestricted form.
- 2 those that are protected by a 3rd party encryption such as former MIP or an Adobe registered plugin [image]

Those in group 2 that are a Modified PDF (thus not true to original spec) would need specialist decoders and at best you would, if possible, just re-print into conventional PDF. Should be easy to see if that's the case by using one of the many more Open PDF readers that dont align themselves with Adobe DRM as may be found in Adobe Digital Editions.

The 1st group with Adobe simple PDF DRM can be opened in any Open Reader such as **FireFox** and thus could be edited in a bookmark editor after stripping the restrictions. Today there are dozens of online and offline tools to remove Adobe PDF "preferences" prior to editing.

**BeCyPDFAsm** and MetaEdit are now abandoned but still work well for "simple protected" PDF archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20180929111456/http://www.becyhome.de/becypdfmetaedit/description_eng.htm and due to Windows newer enhanced security may need to be run using a starter `cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %~pd0\BeCyPDFMetaEdit.com %*"`

Latest JPdfBookmarks includes windows standalone (with JRE = 33 MB) can be found at https://github.com/life888888/JPdfBookmarks HOWEVER I found that recent version unstable while 2.52 is still working well. YMMV !
[image]

Neither would be able from the off to handle a secured file with restrictions such as
[image]
it needs to be unlocked for editing
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a **password remover** can help.

http://securityxploded.com/instant-pdf-password-remover.php

OR, **metadata remover** may help with many things:
http://www.becyhome.de/download_eng.htm

For ***BeCy (MetaEdit and PDFAsm)***, you need additional other programs so please read full info before trying to use it for the first time.

Comment: The Inst.PDF.Pass.Remover does look a wee bit shady, but at least this is something I can try out in a locked down isolated VM.

Comment: Ohh .. the instant PDF Passwd Remover doesn't help, as you need to *know* the password of the file to remove it. Which I don't. I can happily read and view that watermarked file without any problem. I assume that password is just part of the encryption security and of course I wasn't told any. :-/

Answer (score -1):

The challenge with the secure files is just that, they are secure.

I didn't have time today to test this, so I am not sure if this will work on secure PDFs, but [JPdfBookmarks](http://flavianopetrocchi.blogspot.com/) is freeware which helps you add bookmarks to existing PDF files.

Also, here is an article explaining how to do it - [How to add bookmarks to a PDF document (using free software)](http://www.freewaregenius.com/how-to-add-bookmarks-to-a-pdf-document-using-free-software/)

Comment: I tried jPdfBookmarks and doesn't operate on these files.